# How can I prevent "- : unit = ()" from appearing after my output in the ocaml toplevel?

Tags: ocaml

This code

```
for i=0 to 5 do print_string "a" done;;
```

will output

```
aaaaaa- : unit = ()
```

But how can I output just "aaaaaa" without outputting the value of for-expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not really printing the value of the expression; it's just that you are within the session of the interpreter, which by default prints the value/type of the evaluated expression. If you compiled your program it would just print the a's.

Comment: This particular program, when compiled, may not output anything because it lacks some sort of `print_endline()` or `flush stdout`. When I was a student, it was usual to be bitten by this, although perhaps things have changed in the meantime.

Comment: Update: I was referring to http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/FAQ_DEBUTANT-eng.html#impression_flush The problem does not manifest itself with OCaml 3.12, but probably still is in Caml Light.

Answer (score 1):

You could compile your program; this way you won't get the type information from the interpreter -- which is `: unit = ()`